# Linear gradient in svg symbol while using svg-sprite

Tags: html, angular, svg, linear-gradients

I'm using svg sprite in my angular app from external file like that:

```
<svg width="235" height="29" viewBox="0 0 235 29" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <use xlink:href="./assets/img/sprite.svg#logo"></use>
 </svg>
```

Small part of my svg in sprite:

```
<symbol id="logo" viewBox="0 0 235 29" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <path d="M6.73092 6.67399L4.57521 4.29028C3.1336 5.59109 1.98151 7.18038 1.19366 8.95509C0.405817 10.7298 -0.000194815 12.6503 0.00196167 14.592H3.21153C3.21087 13.0993 3.52382 11.6232 4.13009 10.2591C4.73637 8.89513 5.62245 7.6737 6.73092 6.67399Z" fill="url(#paint5_linear)"/>
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="paint5_linear" x1="1.19764" y1="14.9804" x2="5.01264" y2="5.05611" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="0.07" stop-color="#A1CB3A"/>
        <stop offset="0.25" stop-color="#82C35D"/>
        <stop offset="0.92" stop-color="#11A6DE"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
  </symbol>
```

Problem: that those parts where my svg uses id references to linear gradiends not rendering. I have found similar question on Stack Overflow but it solves the problem only using svg sprite in the same file, not external. Would appreciate any help, thank you

Comment: All UAs have a problem here. I guess you can download the source code for Chrome, Firefox and Safari and fix them.